# SQL03006 error when building a Visual Studio 2010 Database Project

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create a VS 2010 DB project. I imported a perfectly working .sql script and was very glad when the database project was created out of this .sql script. But I cannot build it. It throws a lot of SQL03006 error

> "Procedure [SchemaName].[ProcA] has an unresolved reference to object [SchemaName].".

I read articles on how to resolve database and server names but none of those apply to my case. 
My project does not have 4 part or 3 part references - ie, it does not reference a database or server. Only 2-part - [schemaname].[procname].

Why are these errors occuring? How to get past them?

Thanks.

Comment: I found the issue. The schema objects were not created during the import. That is why it can't resolve references to the schema. I went to 'SchemaView' and did 'Add' on the Schemas object and added all my schemas. It builds fine now.

Comment: you should add this as an answer, rather than a comment (if you can)